Can I exclude target/generated-sources from the maven-javadoc-plugin?
I am working on a multi-module project that uses the Maven3 maven-javadoc-plugin, specifically the javadoc:aggregate-jar command.  When this command is run I receive errors from classes generated in the target/generated-sources/ folder.  Is is possible to configure the maven-javadoc-plugin to exclude this directory?
I have attempted to use the excludePackagenames, sourceFileExcludes and dependencySourceExcludes in the POM configuration however it doesn't seem to fix my errors, but I'm unclear if I am configuring it correctly.
